# PHP: Convert portion of binary string in LSBF format to a normal variable?

Tags: php

I have a binary string `$binary` that contains a CRC hash on it.  So it looks like I can extract the binary CRC via `$crc=substr($binary, 0, 4)` but that can't be used to compare against the php `hash()` routine.  So I can `$crc=unpack("V", $crc);` but that gives me an array.   So how do I convert the binary data to a variable I can actually use in PHP such as to compare against the result of the `hash()` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer was to just reference array element [1]:

```
$crc=unpack("V", $crc)[1];
```